# Catch Jbutton pressed not by label

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I would catch by a listener the button pressed but not by the text inside it because I've button only with background image.

This code catch it by label inserted in the jbutton constructor but I don't want show this label.
So or I find a way to hide label on button or I don't insert a label and catch button by some other handle.

```
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    JButton b = (JButton)e.getSource();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"È stato premuto"+b.getActionCommand());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are already getting source object (`b`). What else do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setActionCommand()` to avoid a default action command of the button text.

```
JButton myButton = new JButton();
myButton.setActionCommand("myButtonCommand");

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
  String actionCommand = ae.getActionCommand();
  if (actionCommand.equals("myButtonCommand")) {
    // do something...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageIcon ic=new ImageIcon("C:/image.png");
JButton btn=new JButton(ic);
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        JButton b = (JButton)ae.getSource();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"È stato premuto"+b.getActionCommand());
    }
});
```